# Use cyrillic values in newcommand

Tags: macros, cyrillic

My goal is to be able to write:

```
\newcommand{\сlient_name}{Имя}
```

and use `\client_name` all over in my document. Right now I'm getting following errors like this:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 670--670
[][]|\l_fontspec_font –ü—Ä–æ-–≥—Ä–∞–º-–º–∏-—Ä–æ-–≤–∞-
```

Full errors screenshot here - http://take.ms/opd30

I tried [this SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134387/newcommand-for-foreign-language?newreg=3f3a32f75afd40ecbead25c13da50285) and tried using

```
\newcommand{\сlient_name}{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Имя}}
```

but it didn't help.

How can I accomplish using cyrillic values in /newcommand variables?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't use an underscore in a macro name to begin with.

Comment: I tried to delete all current macros, leaving only one and using camel case. Now I'm getting this error:
`./technical_specification.tex:236: Package microtype Error: Font expansion does not work with xetex.`

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing a minimal document producing the error. But the error message is telling you something, isn't it?

Comment: I tried to google the new error, it leads me to this - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118713/is-microtype-fully-supported-now-by-xelatex-if-not-how-can-i-keep-myself-up-to
Further research leads me to regions which I utterly don't understand. While I generally like the idea of using some sort of semi code to produce documents, this whole bibtex/lualutex/xelatex area drives me insane. I just want to use some simple variables instead of typing text over and over again. But, alas, I will stick to it. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: You *can* define `\clientname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\сlient_name}{Имя}


\begin{document}

\client_name

\end{document}
```

Running XeLaTeX over it reveals

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 \newcommand{\сlient_name}{Имя}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \newcommand{\сlient_name}{Имя}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   n
l.4 \newcommand{\сlient_name}{Имя}

? 
! You already have nine parameters.
\reserved@a ...xpandafter \сlient \reserved@b #10
                                                  n{
l.4 \newcommand{\сlient_name}{Имя}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 

? 
No file mohnstrudel.aux.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \client
           _name
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 \client_
            name
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 

?
```

Note the first error is exactly when `\newcommand` is being attempted. What happens later is completely unpredictable.

Fix the error, which is having `_` in the command name: this is not allowed, see [Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols)

Comment: It is important to switch, whatever it is (looks like a compiler to me) to LuaLaTeX from XeLaTeX. Using the latter one I'm receiving following error: `Package microtype Error: Font expansion does not work with xetex.` (I'm not using an underscore for my variable name).
After switching compiler to the first one I can process the document and generate my pdf!